# Uppercase section in ToC (with hypperref)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, uppercase

I saw already all the links about this problem here at StackOverFlow but none of them could help me. I am trying to change the section names in ToC to uppercase using also the hyperref package but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash,format=hang,font=small]{caption}
\geometry{a4paper,
    top=3cm,
    left=3cm,
    right=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
}

\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}


% MODIFICAR TÍTULOS DAS SEÇÕES DE FIGURAS, TABELAS E SUMÁRIO
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
    \renewcommand\contentsname{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\large\sffamily SUMÁRIO\hspace*{\fill}}
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\large\sffamily LISTA DE FIGURAS\hspace*{\fill}}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\large\sffamily LISTA DE TABELAS\hspace*{\fill}}
}

% AJUSTAR AS SEÇÕES E SUBSEÇÕES
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{1.5cm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\bf\sffamily\large}{\thesection}{20pt}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5cm}{1.5cm}

% MODIFICAR O SUMÁRIO
\titlecontents{section}[1cm]{\bfseries\sffamily}{\contentslabel{3em}}
{\hspace{0em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[1cm]{\sffamily}{\contentslabel{3em}}
{\hspace{0em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1cm]{\sffamily}{\contentslabel{3em}}
{\hspace{0em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% MODIFICAR A LISTA DE FIGURAS
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]{
    Figura~\thecontentslabel \enspace - \enspace
}{}{\hspace{0em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% MODIFICAR LISTA DE TABELAS
\titlecontents{table}[0em]{
    Tabela~\thecontentslabel \enspace - \enspace
}{}{\hspace{0em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please make a *small* but *complete* example.

Comment: Hi @BlackBird your solution was perfect to me. It was simpler than I imagined. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@BlackBird gave me that simplest solution and it worked perfectly. I just needed to put the option in the section command:

```
\section[INTRODUCTION]{Introduction}
```

Thank you for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't process your MWE; there is no `\documentclass` and no `\begin{document}` or `\end{document}`. I see no mention of `hyperref`.

Probably the easiest method is to use the optional argument to the `\section` command which gets put into the ToC and the header. Below I have redefined `\section` to uppercase the ToC entry but eliminated the opportunity to use the optional argument.

```
% sectocprob.tex  SE 566966

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldsec\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsec[\MakeUppercase{#1}]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If you need uppercase in the ToC but not in the headers consider using the `memoir` class which provides two optional section arguments, one for the ToC and the other for headers.