# Uppercase for TOC entries with etocname

Tags: table-of-contents, books, etoc, uppercase

I'm trying to customize my TOC with `etoc` in `book` class, but I'm failing to apply `MakeUppercase` to `\etocname`.
I'm using local TOCs, `hyperref` and `fancyhdr` in case that is relevant.

My main question:

1. How do I make the `\etocname` respect `MakeUppercase`? I already tried all sorts of with/without `{ }` combinations. I also tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156917/115968), but it messes up the `\markboth` command, that I need. [This other solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567305/115968) works, of course, but I don't want to manually change all my `parts`, `chapters` and `sections`. [This option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567118/115968) doesn't work for me because I already use `titlesec` for formatting the in-text appearances of `chapters`, etc.

I also would like to know:

2. Where can I find the etoc-like code for the standard styles in the `book` class? I'm currently guessing the font sizes and `{start}`, `{finish}` codes for each level in the `\etocsetstyle`. I couldn't find this in the `etoc` documentation or elsewhere.

Here is a MWE with my try for changing the `Part` style in TOC:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{part}
{\parindent 0pt
\nobreak
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\large\MakeUppercase\bfseries
\etocifnumbered{\etocnumber{} \ \ \  \MakeUppercase \etocname}{}\nobreak\hfill \etocpage\par}
{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\markboth{contents}{} %I need the solution to work with this

\part{A Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
 \section{A Section} 
  \subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

For reference, here is a pic of what I mean by "standard style", which is what I get if I load the MWE without any `etoc`modifications. [image: standard TOC style]

Comment: About "Where can I find the etoc-like code for the standard styles in the book class?", `29. Emulating the book class` in etoc.pdf contains an answer which adds some features. Maybe you are using an old version whose documentation does not have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could switch to `memoir` class, you could do

```
\makeatletter
\settocpreprocessor{part}{%
  \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
  \def\f@rtoc{%
\MakeUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}}
\makeatother
```

(See p. 162 of Memoir manual if you use hyperref).

Else, perhaps have a look here: [Upper case chapter titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109946/upper-case-chapter-titles-in-the-table-of-contents)

Comment: I can't use memoir, but redefining the command did work, thanks. (For those who, like me, need to discover where to find the original command: look into the [book] class file of your distribution.) It is a bit frustrating though, I thought etoc was supposed to make this sort of approach unnecessary.

Comment: @B.Dors Yes, it would be useful to know wheter the implementation of etoc would allow a simpler solution. Perhaps contact directly the package mantainer? And/or unmark the answer as accepted and wait for someone more competent than I am.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\etocthename` in place of `\etocname`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{part}
{\parindent 0pt
\nobreak
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\large\bfseries
\etocifnumbered{\etocnumber{} \ \ \  \MakeUppercase \etocthename}{}\nobreak\hfill \etocpage\par}
{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\markboth{contents}{} %I need the solution to work with this

\part{A Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
 \section{A Section} 
  \subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

If you use `hyperref` and want the part name to be hyperlinked, you will need a slightly more complex

```
\etoclink{\MakeUppercase \etocthename}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{part}
{\parindent 0pt
\nobreak
\etocskipfirstprefix}
{\pagebreak[3]\bigskip}
{\large\bfseries
\etocifnumbered{\etocnumber{} \ \ \  \etoclink{\MakeUppercase \etocthename}}{}\nobreak\hfill \etocpage\par}
{}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\markboth{contents}{} %I need the solution to work with this

\part{A Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
 \section{A Section} 
  \subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

Note: I removed the first `\MakeUppercase` from your code.

[image: TOC]

Comment: As an aside, using `\etocsetstyle{part}...` triggers etoc package to use its default fall-back styles for the other levels such as `chapter` and `section`, which are not the book class ones.

Comment: Further: the `\etocifnumbered` looks weird.  If the part was not numbered it would choose the *empty* false branch, ionly `\etocpage`   remains then, is that intended?